# Terser CLI: how to remove comments?

Tags: javascript, terser

I'm using this command:

```
npx terser --mangle --compress booleans_as_integers=true --comments false -- $filename
```

However, the comments are all kept. Everything else is compressed. How can I remove the comments?

Edit: This seems to replace all comments with `//`:

```
npx terser --mangle --compress booleans_as_integers=true --comments /$^/ -- $filename
```